# Spring Adding Cookies

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to create a shopping cart using cookies in spring boot but the cookie is not being added/displayed. Below are the controller mappings and page htmls, can you let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Screenshots of pages :

[image: Add To Cart Page]

[image: Show Cookies Page]

Controller Mappings:

```
@GetMapping("/products/addToCart/{id}")
private String addToCart(@PathVariable("id") long productId, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        Cookie browserSessionCookie = new Cookie(Long.toString(productId), Long.toString(1L));
        response.addCookie(browserSessionCookie);
        return "redirect:/products/cart";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        return "fail";
    }
}

@GetMapping("/products/cart")
public String showCookies(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    model.addAttribute("cookies",cookies);
    return "/cart";
}
```

Thymeleaf Page For Products List:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>All Products</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <style>
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        td {
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .topnav {
            background-color: #A32638;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .topnav a {
            float: left;
            color: #f2f2f2;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 17px;
        }

        .topnav a:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
            color: black;
        }

        .topnav a.active {
            background-color: #FCB514;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="topnav">
    <a th:href="@{/}">Home</a>
    <a class="active" th:href="@{/productsList}">Products</a>
    <a th:href="@{/products/cart}">Cart</a>
</div>
<br>
Products&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<br>
<br>
<div th:if="${ not#lists.isEmpty(products)}">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="product : ${products}">
            <td th:text="${product.name}"></td>
            <td th:text="${product.price}"></td>
            <td th:text="${product.category.name}"></td>
            <td>
                <a th:href="@{/products/details/{id}(id=${product.id})}">Details</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a th:href="@{/products/addToCart/{id}(id=${product.id})}">Add To Cart</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thmeleaf Page For Showing Cookies :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<h1>Show cookies</h1>
<dl th:each="cookie : ${cookies}">
    <dt th:text="${cookie.getName()}"></dt>
    <dd th:text="${cookie.getValue()}"></dd>
</dl>
<h1>Session Data</h1>
<dl th:each="elem : ${sessionElems}">
    <dt th:text="${elem.getName()}"></dt>
    <dd th:text="${elem.getValue()}"></dd>
</dl>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Since you're learning, let's try a little troubleshooting.  The problem could be the frontend or the backend, or both.  Let's print a debug statement in the controller and see whether the cookies are present.  If they are not present, then you know that the problem can be traced back to at least the backend and you can come back to the HTML.

Comment: If the debug statement prints the cookie values, then you know you need to look at the HTML.

Comment: Running it with a debugger can also check the values at the controller level.

Comment: You will run through this concept throughout your life as developer, so practice it.

Comment: On first glance, if you look at the Thymeleaf docs, you will also want to follow the syntax like `cookie.name` instead of `cookie.getName().`

Comment: Thank you for the response, I changed the syntax to cookie.name and cookie.value and checked the cookies in controller in debug mode. Only present cookie is JSESSIONID

Comment: Right, so now you know an issue is in the controller layer or prior.  If you create a unit test to test the output of each method, you can not only diagnose what's failing, but have it run for future changes.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to set the path of the created cookie to the path of the cart page as below :

`browserSessionCookie.setPath("/products/cart");`

Thanks for the responses!